# How to give a focus effect to my Draft JS Editor border?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, draftjs

I understand that the draft js editor is not a classic textarea element. I applied some styles to make it look better. However, i can't find this little trick that doing a natural html focus effect when i'm focusing on my draftjs editor. I am not a css expert, i've tried to using the `:active` pseudo class the effect disappear once a release the click.

I just want the borders to be like a classic html input focus effect.

How can a set up this ?

thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can keep track of whether or not the editor has focus by listening for `onFocus` and `onBlur` on it. You can then use this information to set classnames accordingly. Here's an example that makes the border red when it has focus:

https://jsfiddle.net/m7tovuqa/

Comment: Thank you. Great demo. I didn't know the onBlur event listener was taken account in the Editor component. Issue solved